# Change color in CSS of object and specific child for IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

This is my current setup (roughly) in code:

```
<style>
#B {background-color:#F00;color:#00F}
#B H3{background-color:#FF0;color:#000}
</style>
<div ID="B">
<h3>subtitle</h3>
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

This basically sets the color of a box to Blue with background red. Then a header has the color Yellow with background color black.

If I wanted to set the color of the outer box without static CSS, I can easily do this:

```
<div ID="B">
<h3>subtitle</h3>
<p>text</p>
</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById('B').style;
x.color='#F00';
x.backgroundColor='#00F';
</script>
```

Is there a way I can directly access H3 in Javascript that would work for Internet Explorer 7 without assigning an ID value to it?

I'm looking for a code requiring fewer bytes as well as code that produces text to the screen sooner than later.

This site: http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/ states `childnodes[]`, `firstChild`, and a number of other functions that directly work with children of objects are incompatible with IE 7 unless the manual is lying.

Anyone have any idea or will I be stuck with applying an ID tag to each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `getElementsByTagName` is supported from IE5.5

```
<div ID="B">
    <h3>subtitle</h3>
    <p>text</p>
</div>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    if (x and x.style) {

        x.style.color='#F00';

    }
</script>
```

It does return a nodeList (from IE6), so you'd have to use bracket notation, and `[0]` would get the first `<h3>` element on the page.

Comment: So basically, iterating through H3's till I'm lucky to find the right one is the way to go?

Comment: No, you should know which one you want, and use the index of that element. If you want more specific, you add an ID to the element.